# Argument Passing in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to this EmberJS environment and I would to like ask, how do you send parameters to controller functions? I would simply like to filter the model I'm getting. but I don't know how to pass an argument onto the controller. could someone tell me how? any comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Html file:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="favorite/items">
    <ul>
    {{#each i in "filteredItems" }}
        <li>{{i.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

JS file:

```
App.FavoriteItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   filteredItems: function (id) {
    return this.get('model').filterProperty('favoriteId',id);
   }.property('model.@each.favoriteId')
});
```

Comment: What did you get after trying this?

Comment: got nothing, console says it's an error, but if i used filterProperty('favoriteId', 1) . . i'm getting results of models with such properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars is logic-less and you don't pass properties into a computed property. The trick is to make the computed property depend on another property that can change altering your computed property.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="favorite/items">
    <ul>
    {{#each i in filteredItems }}
        <li>{{i.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

JS file:

```
App.FavoriteItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   filteredParam: 1,
   filteredItems: function () {
    var filteredParam = this.get('filteredParam');
    return this.get('model').filterBy('favoriteId',filteredParam);
   }.property('@each.favoriteId', 'filteredParam')
});
```

As you change `filteredParam` ember will consider `filteredItems` as dirty, and recompute it.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/meruli/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I see, I get the point thanks! uhm mind if I ask this too, am I correct in assuming that I need this.set for filteredParam to change its value? sorry still got too many questions in my head that need answers.

Comment: Yes, in order for Ember to be aware that the value has changed you need to use `Ember.set(obj, 'prop', value)` or if the obj extends `Ember.Object`, then you can do `obj.set('prop', value)`